# How to declare string array of unknown size as input then tokenize

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to declare an array of `String` which will consist of the input, that is unknown (it depends what text user inputs). I set up a `Scanner` to read the input then declared a `String[]` to store the input, and a `while` loop to go through each line of text and delimit on " ". My question is: **How do I set up the array of `String` to contain the input so I can break it apart into words in the `while` loop** (I can't use `ArrayList`)

```
public     class Scramble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] words;

        String line;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            words.add(line.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont use arrays... use a list instead...

Comment: Did you try `line.split(" ")`? This would return a String array, where your input String is split up by white space. Also, where is the connection between line and in?

Comment: @IvoVidovic Sorry to be a total newbie but where would I add the line.split method?

Comment: You do not need to apologize. People in SO do not want to attack you with comments, but rather ask for clarifications, because it will also help the community to answer your question.

the split method is actually already there in the String class, so you do not need to add it (if you mean adding in a sense of implementing it yourself). I suggest you to checkout the answer of Scary Wombat. There the split method is used simply after reading out the line with the scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read the whole sentence and do it like this

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence = in.nextLine ();
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

**Input**

this is a test

**Output**

[this, is, a, test]

Comment: Can you do this using a while loop? The objective of the program is to take the letters in a word and scramble them besides the first and last characters

Comment: try to do it yourself - if you can't do it, you can research about it and if still you fail you can post another question.

Comment: @sanclemeteguy try to do something like `words[i]` in your while loop and then try to parse the word. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!

Comment: @HasibMahmud I did something like  `while(hasnext()){
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
   }` and it is not working

Comment: Yeah - what is `hasnext()` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat hasNext is supposed to check while input has next line then continue to break up string on whitespace

Comment: `in.hasNext()` is **not** equal to `hasnext()`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Okay I see.. so how would you recommend I re-structure the while-loop to do its purpose? (I have been researching and looking at the API doc for last few hours, this was an absolute last resort)

Comment: Sorry I am not even following why you want a `while` loop.  My answer allows you to enter a sentence in one go.  Your question mentions breaking it apart into words - where does this `scamble` chars come into play?